# xslt copying element value to over-ride another

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following outbound xml and want to move the value in EndToEndId element to PmtInfId element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
   <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <PmtInf>
         <PmtInfId>98441</PmtInfId>
           <CdtTrfTxInf>
            <PmtId>
               <InstrId>EFT00036798</InstrId>
               <EndToEndId>EFT00036798</EndToEndId>
            </PmtId>
           </CdtTrfTxInf>
      </PmtInf>
   </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

I am using the following xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:wdt="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="1">       
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='PmtInfId']" priority="2">
    <xsl:value-of select="wdt:Document/wdt:CstmrCdtTrfInitn/wdt:PmtInf/wdt:CdtTrfTxInf/wdt:PmtId/wdt:EndToEndId/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is not copying the value to the new element. and the output should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
   <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <PmtInf>
         <PmtInfId>EFT00036798</PmtInfId>
           <CdtTrfTxInf>
            <PmtId>
               <InstrId>EFT00036798</InstrId>
               <EndToEndId>EFT00036798</EndToEndId>
            </PmtId>
           </CdtTrfTxInf>
      </PmtInf>
   </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the a prefix you declare to match and select elements and make sure you use `xsl:copy` to recreate the element if you match on the element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:std="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="std:PmtInfId">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="../std:CdtTrfTxInf/std:PmtId/std:EndToEndId"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  When I add your code above i get the following:  <PmtInfId/> when i run the transformation instead of <PmtInfId>EFT00036798</PmtInfId>.  Is it a namespace issue?

Comment: The sample is complete so I don't know what you have done to "add" the code. At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDk8 the code produces `<PmtInfId>EFT00036798</PmtInfId>` for the input sample you have shown.

Comment: this is the concsole log 14:21:46,730 INFO  [main] Main  - javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseTransformerFactory
14:21:46,732 INFO  [main] Main  - java.endorsed.dirs=\\Mac\Home\Desktop\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching\endorsed
14:21:46,736 INFO  [main] Main  - launchFile: \\Mac\Home\Desktop\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching\launch\launch.xml
14:21:47,227 INFO  [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Transforming...
14:21:47,239 INFO  [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Done.

Comment: @JDavies, I can't tell what goes wrong with your attempt from that comment, perhaps edit the question with full information or start a new one with all information and the right tags for eclipse or wst if the problem occurs in that context.